# Shutdown() Method in example code

Tags: java

Listed below is example code that I found for using the java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService.  The main class includes a shutdown() method that calls the shutdown() method on the ExecutorService.  What I do not understand from this example is when this method would be invoked.

Thanks.

```
package multithreadingexample;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MultithreadingExample {

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

    public void start() throws IOException {
        int i=0;
        while (!executor.isShutdown())
            executor.submit(new MyThread(i++));
    }

    public void shutdown() throws InterruptedException {
        executor.shutdown();
        executor.awaitTermination(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        executor.shutdownNow();
    }

    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
        new MultithreadingExample().start();
    }
}
class MyThread implements Runnable {
    private final int i;

    MyThread(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("I am in thread:"+i);    
    }

}
```

Comment: Just to clarify my question a bit: I understand what MultithreadingExample.shutdown() does, I just don't understand why it's there or how it gets called.  Thanks.

Comment: you have to call it in your main method somewhen.

Comment: You need to call it when you want the program to stop, otherwise the threads in the thread pool just keep on running and the JVM won't stop.

Comment: Thanks.  I was concerned that maybe there was some implicit call that I didn't understand.

Comment: For those that might be interested the example code was taken from here:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.util.concurrent/ExecutorServiceshutdown.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why it is there:
To provide a way to shut down the ExecutorService to stop it from running tasks and to free the threads that it is using.

How it gets called:
You need to call it when you are done using the ExecutorService. In the example code you provided it is not called anywhere.

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html):

> The shutdown() method will allow previously submitted tasks to execute
>   before terminating, while the shutdownNow() method prevents waiting
>   tasks from starting and attempts to stop currently executing tasks.